# Force translated language on front

Tags: translation, localization

I'm facing a really simple issue : We made a theme for a multisite wordpress (see here : http://www.agence-malttt.fr/) and translated it with Loco Translate for French.

It's still showing English version (hardcoded one with _e() ).

My theme now has fr_FR.po and fr_FR.mo, like it was all the time.

The problem is the translation doesn't apply whatever i'm doing.
I've even made changes to wp-config.php and added define('WP_LANG','fr_FR'), changed in general settings and changed in Multisite feature for WP_LANG to be fr_FR too. Still doesn't do the job.

Can someone help us? What did I miss?

Comment: Where did you upload these .po and .mo files. Does the theme come with a .pot file and a language folder?

Comment: It's a copy from the last Twenty<something>, i've changed all occurences, then used the POT contained in themes/my_theme/languages folder for producing mo et po with Loco translate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I made it, it was a problem in po file, missing some arguments or informations in headers. I've generated a new one and replaced with my previously done translations keeping only headers. Loco translate made it work. Cheers !